# How to cancel coroutine when user making new request?

Tags: android, kotlin

When user typing city name in editText it's calling method from viewModel:

```
override fun onTextChanged(text: CharSequence?, start: Int, before: Int, count: Int) {
                handler.removeCallbacksAndMessages(null)
                if (text?.isNotEmpty() == true) {
                    val searchCity = Runnable {
                        viewModel.getWeatherByCityName(text.toString())
                    }
                    handler.postDelayed(searchCity, DELAY)
                }
            }
```

this method in viewModel is making viewModelScope and calling network request from repository by city name:

```
fun getWeatherByCityName(
        cityName: String
    ) {

        viewModelScope.launch {
            weatherRepository.getWeatherByCityName(cityName, localeUnit, localeLang)
                .onEach { dataState ->
                    when (dataState) {
                        is ApiResult.Success -> {
                            prefRepository.setUserInput(cityName)
                            cityId = dataState.data.cityId
                            _screenState.value = dataState
                        }
                        else -> _screenState.value = dataState
                    }
                }
                .launchIn(viewModelScope)
        }
    }
```

So my question is: when user typing a new city name it's calling new method with new network request but the previous coroutine still operating even the user don't need this answer anymore because he want a new one. How can i immediately cancel this coroutine if user calling a new method/new city name for getting new weather?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can keep a reference to the `job` and check if it's not null (meaning that there is an existing request) and cancel it then start a new one

in `ViewModel`

```
private val job: Job? = null
```

and in you function

```
fun getWeatherByCityName(
        cityName: String
    ) {

        if (job != null) {
            job.cancel()
        }
        job = viewModelScope.launch {
            
        }
    }
```

Comment: So when at the beggining of the method we have any job in this we closing it? But what about completion of this coroutine? It will wait when coroutine is complited and then closing it or it's closing it immediately? I mean should we use `join` after closing or not?

Comment: Kotlin won’t smart cast a mutable property.  Use `job?.cancel()` without the if statement. The job will stop at its next suspension point or immediately if it is currently suspended. You don’t need to join it.

Comment: @R.Milos could you please explain your question if you S ill have a one?